# How to sum the duplicate values from mysql table

Tags: mysql, sum, sql-order-by

i wanted to retrieve the sum of duplicate USD amount from below table with respect to date and ref_nr columns

```
uid         date       USD      Ref_Nr
1     2018-04-11    1       7 
1     2018-04-11    2       7
1     2018-04-11    3       8
1     2018-04-11    4       8
1     2018-04-11    6       6
1     2018-04-11    6       6 
1     2018-04-10    3       7
1     2018-04-10    5       7
1     2018-04-10    2       8
1     2018-04-10    2       8
```

Here is my sql query and what i tried, but iam not getting proper output, please help me

```
SELECT  uid 
     ,  date 
     , SUM(USD) AS USD 
     ,  Ref_Nr  
  FROM my_table
 GROUP 
    BY `date`;
```

Here is expected output

```
uid         date       USD      Ref_Nr 
1     2018-04-11    3       7  
1     2018-04-11    7       8 
1     2018-04-11    12      6 
1     2018-04-10    8       7 
1     2018-04-10    4       8
```

Comment: @Strawberry , i have updated the above question , pls check

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: id is my primary key in my table , but i have not added in above question

Comment: If you want to sum by date and ref_nr; you need to add ref_nr and UID to the group by.  If that still doesn't work then date must be a date time and you need to cast to date. so time goes away.  `GROUP BY Date, Ref_Nr, uid`  When using aggregation it is wise to group by all the fields in the select not part of the aggregate.  MySQL may let you get away w/o it due to how they extend the group by; but few other RDBMS systems will let you do this.  And you have to be very careful when using in MySQL.  IN your case I bet Ref_Nr was the same value for each date giving only 1 row per dt.

Comment: You should always state your PK.

Comment: Is the order of the results important? If not, then xQbert has your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  uid 
     ,  date 
     , SUM(USD) AS USD 
     ,  Ref_Nr  
  FROM my_table
 GROUP 
    BY `date`, Ref_Nr, uid;
```

In this case you must have Ref_Nr in the group by to get the desired results.  uid, based on sample data, isn't needed; but it is wise to always group by the non-aggregated fields from the select in the group by.  The only reason this works in mySQL is because they [extend the group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html); most other RDBMS would throw an error about the missing non-aggregated fields in the group by.  In version 5.7.5 and higher this feature is disabled by default where enabled by default prior.

**As to why ref_nr is needed in the group by:**

The mySQL engine  believes you want to just group by date.  So all the ref_NR's get summed together and the system simply picks one per date to display; same for uid; but since they are all the same; you don't care.  This in'st the case with the ref_nr.

So to resolve the issue, just add `ref_nr` to the group by and out of good from add `UID`.  So it is good from to group by all non-aggregated columns from the select into the group by.